# Kind of limitation in shortcode for WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this function:

```
function movie_cast( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $url = '/?s=';
    $str = '';
    foreach (explode(", ",$content) as $content)
{
        if ($str != "") $str .= ", ";
        $str .= '<a href=\'' . $url . $content . '\'>' . $content . '</a>';
}
    return '<div class="movie_cast" style="display: block; margin-left: 180px;"><strong>Cast: </strong>'.$str.'<br><br></div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'movie_cast', 'movie_cast' );
```

This is the shortcode which break the post (post is empty):

[movie_cast]James Marsden, Joel Rogers, Will Ferrell, Christina Applegate, Paul Rudd, Steve Carell, David Koechner, Fred Willard, Bill Kurtis, Luke Wilson, Vince Vaughn, Dylan Baker, Liam Neeson, Harrison Ford, Steve Coulter, Sacha Baron Cohen, Greg Kinnear, Jim Carrey, John C. Reilly, Kristen Wiig, L. Warren Young, Arvell Poe, Kirsten Dunst, Shade Rupe, Amy Poehler, Meagan Good, Nicole Kidman, Josh Lawson, Brian F. Durkin, Wilbur Fitzgerald, Tina Fey, Ron Prather, Kanye West, Karen Beyer, Sarah E. Spencer, June Diane Raphael, Lori Beth Edgeman, Zoe Myers, Matthew Stanton, Kate Nowlin, Gary Weeks, Chris Gethard, Charles Casey, Dane Davenport, Lauren Henneberg, Victor Gage, Nickolas Wolf, Clark Sarullo, Dave Pileggi, Ken Venzke, David Silverman, James Smith, Randall Taylor, Tom Clark, Judah Nelson, C.C. Ice, King, William Frasca, David Pascua, Amanda Q Williams, Gina Santiago, Jeff Matthew Glover, Gary Miller, John J. Palomino, Christopher Payne, Nancy Sandlin, Don Teems, Rachel Acuna, Paul Chappell, Fred Galle, Dawn Hamil, Gelin DiGennaro, Jennifer Gullick, Rose Hughes, Natalie Taylor, Dave Simmons, Rob Tunstall, Gary Hardt, Clay Stapleford, Robert F. Nixon, David Itchkawitz, Jessica Brown, Courtney Patterson, Alberto David Mercado, Joseph Nelson, Olivia Austin, Kevin Tomkins, Colin Lacativa, Matt Amick, Lane Gamble, Zeb Austin, Larry A. Brewer, Ellie Decker, Lisa Finlayson, Daniel T. Martin, Courtney Pennington, Brandi Quinn, Paul Vincent Rapisarda[/movie_cast]

If I write less of the actors inside the shortcode it works than.
From where this limitation is coming?
How I can fix this?

Update:
As suggested in the comments, I have tried to echo $str, what seems to be working.
This function works for unlimited characters divided by comma:

```
function movie_cast( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $url = '/?s=';
    $str = '';
    foreach (explode(", ",$content) as $content)
{
        if ($str != "") $str .= ", ";
        $str .= '<a href=\'' . $url . $content . '\'>' . $content . '</a>';
}
    echo $str;
}
add_shortcode( 'movie_cast', 'movie_cast' );
```

Comment: I presume you are using a plugin? If so, make sure to check the forums to see if there are any other people with the same issue. If you are using a plugin please provide the name.

Comment: This is not a plugin. I wrote this shortcode to use it in movie review posts. Yes, it is Anchorman movie, I found a lot of actors in this movie, and noticed for first time that my code is limitted somehow.

Comment: @user3114390 - can you do a little debugging? Is there a specific limit to how many actors you need to remove before it'll work? What happens if you swap actors round? Does it look like it's a limit of characters, or of actors?

Comment: Hi, andrewsi. I used:"a, a, a,..." to test and answer on your question. 92 of the "a" will work, 93 of the "a" will break the post.

Comment: @user3114390 - if you use `@username`, then the user gets a note to say you've replied; you'll get a faster response. I can't see any reason why this would be limited to 92, though I'm very curious as to what might be going on. When you say it breaks the post, can you describe what happens? Do you get a completely white screen? If you view the source of the page, is there anything there? About all I can think of is that maybe there's enough code to break your style?

Comment: @andrewsi, actually it is 91 - works, 92 - breaks, I have counted now several times with just "a" letters. Breaks, I mean all post content disappears, I have empty div, it is not just that this code content disappear, but all post content with it. Also, it is not completely white screen, I see everything except post content, and in inspect element content is empty div: "<div class="entry-inner"></div>".

Comment: @user3114390 - OK. Let's see if we can take it one step at a time. The next step I'd suggest would be to remove the `$str` from your return, and replace it with a fixed string of `Test`. That will show us if there's an issue with the function generating the code, or with the return part.

Comment: @andrewsi, it returns "Cast: Test", everything is working ok.

Comment: @user3114390 - Then it's an issue with the function itself. Which is weird. Next step - instead of returning `$str`, can you echo it out? That will break the formatting for sure, but you'll be able to see the content. Can you edit it into your question?

Comment: @andrewsi, I tried echo and it works. See up in question, I updated it.

Comment: @user3114390 - then I think I'm stumped. There should be no difference between echoing out the code and returning it; unless WordPress is doing something to it before it's output, as that's the only difference between the two. It's not a rogue character in your HTML, because none of the cast list you've included have apostrophes in their names; so I can only guess that it's something in WordPress's shortcode handling

Comment: @andrewsi, any way to echo it without break the formatting?

Comment: @user3114390 - you could always try echoing out the whole thing, with your `<div>` wrapped around it - basically replace the `return` in your original code with `echo`

Comment: @andrewsi, that's exactly what I'm doing, but it shows first at page, in other words:"it jumps out it's position and shows first inside the div".

Comment: @user3114390 - Ah, yes; because it's echoing when the function is called. I really don't know what else to suggest - I'm bemused that this works with 91 entries, but a 92nd breaks it. The only things I can think of are posting on wordpress.stackexchange.com to see if someone there has any ideas; or to add a limit to your code to stop the loop on the 91st iteration.

Comment: @andrewsi, that's probably wordpress limitation. Can you please give answer how to stop the loop on the 91st iteration, I will accept it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, it seems to be an issue with WordPress when you return the results - 91 is fine, 92 is not. My suggestion is to re-write your loop so that it only does a maximum of 91 iterations:

```
function movie_cast( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $url = '/?s=';
    $str = '';

    $output = array();
    $count = 0;

    foreach (explode(", ",$content) as $content) {
        $count++;
        $output[] = "<a href='" . $url . $content . "'>" . $content . "</a>";
        if ($count == 91) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return implode(", ", $output);
}
```

I've amended the code a little - it's storing everything in an array, so you don't need to check each time and add a comma separately; instead, it's imploding the array at the end to generate the string.

I've also swapped the string so it's delimited by double quotes, just so there's less escaping required.